# Form action call to insert data to database in Framework 1

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I am learning Framework1 and tried to do a simple ColdFusion program to insert data into database after submitting a form.

My simple form `person.cfm` is in `views/main`

```
<form name = "savePerson" action="#buildurl('person')#" method="post">
```

In the form action I put controller `person.cfc`

I have `person.cfc` in `controllers` folder with code in the component

```
<cffunction name="person">
  <cfif isDefined("rc.savePerson")>
    <cfset variables.services.person.savePerson()>
  </cfif>
</cffunction
```

and SQL insert statement in `person.cfc` with function name = `savePerson` in the `services` folder.

Application.cfc has code

```
 function setupApplication() {

    var bf = new framework.ioc( "services" );

    setBeanFactory( bf );

 }
```

When I submit the form I get the error below

> Original exception in onRequest
>
> The action person.person failed.
>
> Element SERVICES.PERSON is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String; referenced as ''
>
> (Expression)

but there is a `person.cfc` in `controllers`, `services`. I don't know if I need a `beans` folder.
My question is what should I write for form action and how Framework1 will call the file in services folder to run insert statement via controller?

Comment: You should probably post this to the FW/1 Google Group - http://groups.google.com/group/framework-one

Comment: Looks like you did post this to the FW/1 Google Group. Here is a link to that - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/framework-one/IUXOEVq9eSo

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you might be missing get/set to the Person Service. Also make sure you've got the service declared in the beans.xml.cfm

**controllers/person.cfc**

```
<cffunction name="setPersonService" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="personService" type="any" required="true" />
    <cfset variables.personService = arguments.personService />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="getPersonService" access="public" returntype="any" output="false">
    <cfreturn variables.personService />
</cffunction>
```

**assets/config/beans.xml.cfm**

```
<bean id="personService" class="myapp.services.Person" singleton="true">
</bean>
```

Edit: Oh I just realised this question was answered on the FW/1 groups